# How can I make windows minimize using middle mouse button on title bar in Xubuntu?

Tags: mouse, window-management, xubuntu

Running Ubuntu 12.10 with Xubuntu-Desktop. Would like window to minimize if I middle-click on its title bar. Can't find any setting for this. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible- I have been experimenting with `xdotool` and `xbindkeys`, and they are mostly all you need to pull it off, so please enter

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool xbindkeys x11-utils xinput
```

Now, your middle mouse button is usually button 2, but you can check by using `xev` and clicking in the event tester box, or looking at the output of `xinput`. Enter `xinput` and that will list your devices, so note the id for your mouse and then enter

```
xinput list-props < device id >
```

to find details on your mouse buttons. You can always choose a different mouse button if your middle button doesn't register properly or is unavailable.

---

The `xdotool` command you need for what you want to do is:

```
xdotool getactivewindow windowminimize
```

This command minimises the active window; however this action must also be associated with mouse button 2 and the way to do that is to use `xbindkeys`. We place the above command in `~/.xbindkeysrc` (see below) and associate it with the middle mouse button (`b:2`), so that the depressing of mouse button 2 triggers the `xdotool` command.

(This `xdotool` command will work in the terminal if executed and will minimize it, so showing that it is the necessary command for what you want.)

This entry **must** be placed in your `~/.xbindkeysrc`:

```
"xdotool getactivewindow windowminimize"
b:2
```

The `xdotool` command must also be enclosed in quotes (as above) when placed in that file.

So that `xbindkeys` re-reads the file, you can clear current bindings with `killall xbindkeys` and then just execute `xbindkeys` to restart it.

Now your command will be available; `xbindkeys` doesn't seem to need to be put in startup for me, and you can run your command without rebooting; you can cancel it any time again by entering `killall xbindkeys` and then editing your `~/.xbindkeysrc`.